# Divide N sticks among M boys as homogeneously as possible (ignoring order)

Tags: algorithms, optimization, integer-partitions

There are $N$ sticks. $N$ is an integer greater than zero. I want to divide it among $M$ boys. $M$ is also a positive integer. Partitioning $N$ among $M$ is easy, but doing it as evenly as possible is difficult for me to think through. Can someone suggest an algorithm? Similar questions exist on this site, but I could not find an answer that solves this problem, though it is possible that I overlooked something.

**EDIT:**

The sticks are all homogeneous, the same in every respect. What I mean by "as evenly as possible" is that if there are 6 sticks and 3 boys, the division algorithm should output 2-2-2. If there are 5 sticks among 3 boys, it should output 1-2-2. The disparity between the minimum stick holder and maximum stick holder should be minimized. Ordering does not matter (e.g. 1-2-2 is the same as 2-1-2).

Comment: What do you mean by "as equally as possible"? Are the sticks of different lengths/weights? Do you have a link to this problem somewhere? This description seems filled with ambiguity.

Comment: @ryan clarified above.

Comment: You tag "optimization", but what do you want to optimize? Giving everybody nothing it perfectly equal. See [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/30073/98) for a more interesting variant.

Comment: OK, strictly speaking, essentially everything is an algorithm. But you just need to do division, here.

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366327/dividing-a-integer-equally-in-x-parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Divide perfectly homogeneously, as large as possible
for i = 0 to M
    array[i] = N / M    # integer division, resulting in floor

# Divide remainder
for i = 0 to N modulus K
    array[i] += 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Give some of the boys $\lfloor N/M \rfloor$ sticks (i.e., divide and round down), and some of them $\lceil N/M \rceil$ sticks (divide and round up).  Once you fix those two numbers, that uniquely determines how many boys get $\lfloor N/M \rfloor$ sticks and how many get $\lceil N/M \rceil$ sticks -- do some simple arithmetic, try a few examples, use the fact that $\lceil N/M \rceil = \lfloor N/M \rfloor + 1$ if $M$ doesn't evenly divide into $N$, and you'll work out the general formula.

Answer (score 0):

Give them $\lfloor\frac{N}{M}\rfloor$ sticks and then distribute the rest of sticks ($N-\lfloor\frac{N}{M}\rfloor$) among them by giving one stick to each boy until there are no more sticks. 
By solving it this way, the time complexity will be $\max(\lfloor\frac{N}{M}\rfloor, N \bmod M)$ .

Comment: What do you mean by "$[N/M]$"? That's not a notation I've seen before.

Comment: It means the integer part of [N/M]

Comment: Oh, and I have made a mistake about time complexity

Comment: OK. That's usually written $\lfloor N/M\rfloor$ (`\lfloor ... \rfloor` in LaTeX).

Comment: Yes that is notation for floor.  The same upside dow is ceiling.  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions